# How can i fin the index using exponential, binary or interpolatin search recursively?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

> Given an array of n integers A[0…n−1], such that ∀i,0≤i≤n, we have that |A[i]−A[i+1]|≤1, and if A[0]=x, A[n−1]=y, we have that x<y. Locate the index j such that A[j]=z, for a given value of z, x≤ z ≤y

I dont understand the problem. I've been stuck on it for 4 days. Any idea of how to approach it with binary search, exponential search or interpolation search recursively? We are given an element z find the index j such that a [j] = z (a j) am i right?.

```
static int binarySearch(int[] searchArray, int x) {
                    int start, end, midPt;
                    start = 0;
                    end = searchArray.length - 1;
                    while (start <= end) {
                            midPt = (start + end) / 2;
                            if (searchArray[midPt] == x) {
                                    return midPt;
                            } else if (searchArray[midPt] < x) {
                                    start = midPt + 1;
                            } else {
                                    end = midPt - 1;
                            }
                    }
                    return -1;
            }
```

Comment: Elements of array are distinct?

Comment: Ok...We can assume that the elements are not distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basic binary search algorithm. The fact that `A[i]` and `A[i+1]` differ by at most 1 guarantees you will find a match.

Pseudocode:

```
search(A, z):
  start := 0
  end := A.length - 1
  while start < end:
    x = A[start]
    y = A[end]
    mid := (start+end)/2
    if x <= z <= A[mid]:
      end := mid
    else if A[mid] < z <= y
      start := mid + 1
  return start
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily return the first match, but that wasn't required.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how do you binary search unsorted data?

Comment: @geobits: Binary search: check the item in the middle. If the item you are looking for is to the left, go left. If the item is to the right, go right. You don't need sorted data to decide if "z" is on the right or on the left.

Comment: @geobits: -2 does not fulfill the rules, z must be between the first and last items in the array.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I see what you're getting at now. I was searching for the *first* z, not necessarily *any* z. +1

Answer (score 0):

to apply your algorithms your need a sorted array.
the condition of you problem says that you have an array which has elements that differ with max 1, not necessarily sorted!!!

so, here are the steps to write the code :

1. check if problem data respects given conditions
2. sort input array + saving old indexes values, so later can can initial positions of elements
3. implement you search methods in recursive way
4. [Binary search source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
5. [Interpolation search source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search)

Here's full example source :

```
public class Test {

// given start ======================================================
public int[] A = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8 };
public int z = 4;
// given end =======================================================

public int[] indexes = new int[A.length];

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test test = new Test();
    if (test.z < test.A[0] || test.z > test.A[test.A.length - 1]){
        System.out.println("Value z="+test.z+" can't be within given array");
        return;
    }
    sort(test.A, test.indexes);
    int index = binSearch(test.A, 0, test.A.length, test.z);
    if (index > -1) {
        System.out.println("Binary search result index =\t"
                + test.indexes[index]);
    }
    index = interpolationSearch(test.A, test.z, 0, test.A.length-1);
    if (index > -1) {
        System.out.println("Binary search result index =\t"
                + test.indexes[index]);
    }
}

public static void sort(int[] a, int[] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        b[i] = i;
    boolean notSorted = true;
    while (notSorted) {
        notSorted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                int aux = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = aux;
                aux = b[i];
                b[i] = b[i + 1];
                b[i + 1] = aux;
                notSorted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static int binSearch(int[] a, int imin, int imax, int key) {
    // test if array is empty
    if (imax < imin)
        // set is empty, so return value showing not found
        return -1;
    else {
        // calculate midpoint to cut set in half
        int imid = (imin + imax) / 2;

        // three-way comparison
        if (a[imid] > key)
            // key is in lower subset
            return binSearch(a, imin, imid - 1, key);
        else if (a[imid] < key)
            // key is in upper subset
            return binSearch(a, imid + 1, imax, key);
        else
            // key has been found
            return imid;
    }
}

public static int interpolationSearch(int[] sortedArray, int toFind, int low,
        int high) {

    if (sortedArray[low] == toFind)
        return low;

    // Returns index of toFind in sortedArray, or -1 if not found
    int mid;

    if (sortedArray[low] <= toFind && sortedArray[high] >= toFind) {
        mid = low + ((toFind - sortedArray[low]) * (high - low))
                / (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low]); // out of range is
                                                            // possible here
        if (sortedArray[mid] < toFind)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (sortedArray[mid] > toFind)
            // Repetition of the comparison code is forced by syntax
            // limitations.
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
        return interpolationSearch(sortedArray, toFind, low, high);

    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Is that ... bubble sort? [There are way better sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts). But you can really just call `Arrays.sort`. Note that sorting takes longer than doing a straight-forward check-every-element linear search.

Comment: @Dukeling sorting algorithm is out of scope here, a just showed that he needs to save indexes during sorting, and in this case i can't use `Arrays.sort` because well lose indexes.